# Truncate string error

Tags: c#, sql, string, error-handling

I have this string "SP-CTe-10-10-2012". SQL insertion gives this error "string or binary would be truncated, "

I have tried this :

```
string verapli1 = _infProt_verAplic.ToString();
string verapli2 =verapli1.Substring (verapli1.Length ,20);
```

to reduce the length of the string but this code has the error too.

Comment: What is the column width, of this field in your database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your column string length is lower than your string length.

Increase datatype length (try changing the column type to `varchar(20)`) or decrease length of value before insertion.

Answer (score 0):

That is a SQL Server error - means your string won't fit in the field you're trying to insert it in. BTW don't store dates as strings - that's bad design.

Answer (score 0):

IT should be,

```
string verapli1 = _infProt_verAplic.ToString();
if(verapli1.Length > 20)
verapli1 =verapli1.Substring (0,20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is SQL 
                    lenght of the column  nvarchar(15),
   when i write the procedure i assign to variabel

```
             alter proc probandodata (@dhre nvarchar(30))as
             insert into ctrc5 (veraplic,numero)
             values(@dhre,5555555)
```

I only adjust dhre to nvarchar to @dhre nvarchar(15) and works fine. ThansK.